# Posso fazer o versionamento de um Documento Word no Git

Tags: git, versionamento

Gostaria de fazer um teste no Git fazendo o versionamento de um documento Word qualquer por exemplo:

1. Digitar um linha qualquer e commitar
2. Digitar outra linha e commitar
3. Voltar da versão 2 para a versão 1 e verificar o documento word se está como no  primeiro passo.

Comment: Fala aí, Lauro! Vou te dar uma dica: nas suas próximas perguntas, lembre-se de relatar suas buscas, mencionar suas tentativas, demostre esforço e especifique exatamente onde você não entendeu/conseguiu fazer. Dessa vez respondi pq é coisa simples e deu pra entender seu objetivo no enunciado. Mas não deixe de considerar para as próximas! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Vou fazer um exemplo para que você entenda:

## 1) Crie uma pasta qualquer para o versionamento;

## 2) Dentro desta pasta, inicie o *Git*:

```
git init
```

> Initialized empty Git repository in [`caminho da pasta`]/.git/

## 3) Crie um arquivo no *Word* e salve nesta pasta:

[image: Texto no word]

## 4) Ver os *status do git*:

```
git status
```

> On branch master
>
> No commits yet
>
> Untracked files:
>     (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> ```
>    documento-word-2013.docx
>    ~$cumento-word-2013.docx
> ```
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

## 5) Fazer o primeiro *commit*:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Documento criado"
```

## 6) Fazer uma alteração no arquivo do *Word* e salvar:

[image: Segundo texto no word]

## 7) Fazer o segundo *commit*:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Adicionado segundo texto lorem"
```

## 8) Ver a lista de *commits*:

```
git log
```

> commit **97ccced5fc1f03bf8a4c1747be6915039f384c9c** (HEAD -> master)
>
> Author: lipespry
>
> Date:   Thu Jan 10 04:59:49 2019 -0200
>
> `Adicionado segundo texto lorem`
>
> commit **2e5e1914988c4aab4d83e57aa0b59254da4fbe18**
>
> Author: lipespry
>
> Date:   Thu Jan 10 04:58:12 2019 -0200
>
> `Documento criado`

## 9) Voltar para o primeiro *snapshot*:

```
git checkout 2e5e1914988c4aab4d83e57aa0b59254da4fbe18
```

> Note: checking out '2e5e1914988c4aab4d83e57aa0b59254da4fbe18'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
>   changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
>   state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
>   do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
>
> `git checkout -b <new-branch-name>`
>
> **HEAD is now at 2e5e191 Documento criado**

## 10) Abrir o arquivo e verificar como está:

[image: Arquivo na primeira versão]

**@edit** (agradecimentos ao [Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado)):

É uma pena, mas o *Git* não detalha as alterações nos documentos do *Word* (`git diff`). Pelo menos não nativamente.

Comment: Se não tem qualidade e nem esforço, o ideal seria comentar você não acha? Melhor seria não ter colocado esse paragrafo.

Comment: @NoobSaibot Até que não é má ideia. Feito! ;)

Comment: Só uma pergunta: ao fazer uma alteração e salvar o documento, o que o `git diff` acusa?

Comment: @LipESprY perfeito. É que se o formato docx for textual, o git trabalhará bem com ele. Agora, se for um grande blob binário, vai virar uma bagunça nas partes internas pela minha lembrança. Git trabalha muito bem com versionamento textual

Comment: @LipESprY edita o arquivo e salva, ou tenta ver o `git log 2e5e191`

Comment: Nem mesmo o GitHub consegue *diffar* as alterações. Veja este [commit](https://github.com/lipespry/teste-git-word/commit/ca205a0bbf30ba7d8dcfb1e6664ab92be8939751)... No `git log` não mostra exatamente as alterações. Só a mensagem do commit e informações básicas, como autor, data, hora, etc...

Comment: "Binary file not shown"... é, vai acontecer alguma bagunça com a compactação do git...

Comment: Acredito que, ao invés da bagunça, não haja compactação direta... Vai saber, né?! kk

Comment: Obrigado @LipESprY, ajudou muito.

Comment: @LauroBrizidio Por nada! Aliás, a comunidade recomenda que ao solucionar seu problema, aceite a resposta como tal.

Comment: O mais importante - que é ignorar os arquivos temporários que o Word cria quando um usuário abre o arquivo - não foi colocado na resposta. O problema mais comum de quem versiona arquivos do word e persistir temporários, causando conflitos intermináveis...

Comment: inclusive, percebi agora, a resposta inclui um temporário no commit. O OP vai ficar frustrado quando ver a quantidade de problemas causados...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Nunca versionei arquivo do Word. Mas já versionei outros arquivos e formulei minha resposta baseando-me em tal. Quanto aos arquivos temporários, acho que eles são criados ao abrir o arquivo e são deletados logo assim que termina o trabalho (quando fecha o word). Não vejo isso como um perigo ao versionamento. Que tal formular uma resposta relatando sua experiência? Será de grande utilidade para futuros curiosos.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado justamente. Quando eu rodei `git status` o Word estava aberto. Fechei-o e o arquivo não entrou no versionamento. Outra questão: No exemplo, ainda que tenha feito com o word aberto, adicionei todos os arquivos. Então, se futuramente ele fizer um checkout, vai "restaurar" ambos os arquivos. Seria redundante...

Comment: Exatamente @LipESprY - e no teu exemplo, tu commitaste com o arquivo aberto, persististe um binário temporário que será baixado por outro usuário, isso invariavelmente causará conflitos insolúveis quando há mais de um usuário utilizando o mesmo arquivo Word. Por isso acho importante ensinar também o uso do `.gitignore` para ignorar tais arquivos

Comment: É, neste caso, o recomendado é utilizar uma ferramenta de versionamento compatível. Edição em grupo no mesmo arquivo, ainda mais no word, não é coisa pro git...